# Angular *ngFor with tr yields unexpected behavior

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
   <tr *ngFor="let company of [].constructor(3)">
     <td>
          {{companyDetails?.description}}
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Let companyDetails?.description be a large string, then the output for the above is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Nhg.png). Basically it appears row-wise instead of column-wise.

However, if I manually write the code i.e.

```
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{companyDetails?.description}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{companyDetails?.description}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{companyDetails?.description}}
        </td>
      </tr>
```

then I get the correct output like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IJEB.png)

Also, using *ngFor with tr is also messing with the cell placement within the table.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it seems you want your ngFor on <td> not on <tr>

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating over your rows instead of your columns, change to this:

```
  <tr>
     <td *ngFor="let company of [].constructor(3)">
          {{companyDetails?.description}}
     </td>
   </tr>
```